# How to get main window handle from a child window handle

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get handle to main window from foreground window.

```
hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

hwndOwner = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER);
hwndParent = GetParent(hWnd);
```

`hwndOwner` and `hwndParent` are just one layer above the foreground window.  How do I get main window handle without recursively calling above functions?

Comment: Please, include a Minimal Reproducible Example. Read: "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What makes you think the foreground window has the main window as its owner/parent window to begin with? Did you verify that with a tool like Spy++?

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetAncestor with the GA_ROOT flag:
GetAncestor(hwndChild, GA_ROOT);

Note that I am not certain of the difference between GA_ROOT and GA_ROOTOWNER.

Comment: this returns same HWND value as the child window for some reason

Comment: And GA_PARENT gives me desktop handle

Comment: If `GA_ROOT` returns the input `HWND`, and `GA_PARENT` returns the Desktop, then the input `HWND` wasn't a child window to begin with, it was a top-level window. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64706272/65863) to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705850/) on this issue.