# GetAncestor behaving weirdlly

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HWND hwnd; 
HWND hParent;
HWND hwnd;

hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
hParent = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_PARENT);
hTop = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOT);
```

hParent is the Desktop handle and hTop is same as hwnd, instead of returning parent and top-level window. Why is that?

Comment: What are the actual handles and relationships involved? Use something like WinSpy++ to check and then create an example that has all the information necessary to answer the question. You're asking a question about a specific circumstance with no details on that circumstance.

Comment: Why would you expect the system to behave this way?

Comment: I thought `GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_PARENT)` would behave same as `GetParent(hwnd)`. I guess `GetParent` was returning the owner. Missed that part in MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Per [About Windows: Parent or Owner Window Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows#parent-or-owner-window-handle):

> A window can have a parent window. A window that has a parent is called a child window. The parent window provides the coordinate system used for positioning a child window. Having a parent window affects aspects of a window's appearance; for example, a child window is clipped so that no part of the child window can appear outside the borders of its parent window.
>
> **A window that has no parent, or whose parent is the desktop window, is called a *top-level window*.** An application can use the [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) function to obtain a handle to each top-level window on the screen. EnumWindows passes the handle to each top-level window, in turn, to an application-defined callback function, [EnumWindowsProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms633498(v=VS.85).aspx).
>
> A top-level window can own, or be owned by, another window. An owned window always appears in front of its owner window, is hidden when its owner window is minimized, and is destroyed when its owner window is destroyed. For more information, see [Owned Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows).

The fact that `GA_PARENT` is returning the Desktop `HWND`, but `GA_ROOT` is returning the input `HWND`, means that `GetForegroundWindow()` is returning an `HWND` of a *top-level window* whose parent is the Desktop.  `GA_ROOT` is stopping before it reaches the Desktop since the input `HWND` as already at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

> hParent is the Desktop handle

From this result, the `hwnd` is a top-level window.

> A top-level window, on the other hand, has no parent. Its parent is
> NULL.

From this point of view, the root window is itself since it has no parent. So *"hTop is same as hwnd"* is expected.

Refer to "[What's so special about the desktop window?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040224-00/?p=40493)" and "[A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613)".

Consider this situation: Window A has a child window B, B has a child window C. At this time:

```
// hWindowC is HWND of window C; hWindowB is HWND of window B; hWindowA is HWND of window A
hWindowB = GetAncestor(hWindowC, GA_PARENT);
hWindowA= GetAncestor(hWindowC, GA_ROOT);
```